# Error when making opencv

Tags: python, opencv, cmake, fedora

i have fedora 23 - 32 bit, and i'm trying to install opencv 3.0.0.
when performing this step in the terminal:

```
sudo make
```

i got this:

```
...
[ 26%] Built target opencv_hal
[ 32%] Built target opencv_core
[ 33%] Built target opencv_flann
[ 34%] Built target opencv_ml
[ 41%] Built target opencv_imgproc
[ 44%] Built target opencv_photo
[ 45%] Built target opencv_imgcodecs
[ 46%] Built target opencv_video
[ 46%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so
[ 46%] Built target opencv_shape
/lib/libbz2.so.1: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/build.make:283: recipe for target 'lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.0.0' failed
make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.0.0] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4279: recipe for target 'modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:149: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

what should i do?

Comment: You have to install bz2 libraries. `yum install bzip2-devel` or `apt-get install libbz2`

Comment: @pbu Thank you very very much :) , it's working

Comment: dont run make as superuser, only make install if the build is succesfull ofcourse.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install bz2 libraries.

`yum install bzip2-devel`

or in debian

`apt-get install libbz2`